# Pylint Not Rerunning

Tags: python, pylint

I have what may be a silly question.  I'll run pylint on the CLI and it will list the things it doesn't like.

The command I'm using to run pylint is: `pylint ./src`.

I'll then make whatever changes it suggests and execute the same command.  However, it doesn't seem to be rescanning my code.  Instead it seems to simply resend the same cached results.

I've never enountered this before and I'm wondering if there is some way to disable this behavior?

Comment: This may seem like a silly answer, but did you save your changes? Are the changes made in the `./src` directory?  pylint should indeed rescan files every time you run it afaik.

Comment: I don't know what was happening but I use PyCharm and for whatever reason, I found that it was simply not saving my work.  Restarting PyCharm a few times seemed to do the trick.